# ICS_Subscription enable ICS Sharing

Tags: solspace-calendar

The docs say

"To enable this feature, make sure to enable ICS Sharing, click the green icon button in Manage column for the applicable calendar(s) on the list view of calendars in the Calendar control panel. "

And I don't see how to enable this anywhere in the current build of Calendar.

Please send a clue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure you're using [Calendar 2.3.0+](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/docs/changelog/)

Then, go to CP -> Calendar -> Calendars page and you'll see the button in the **Manage** column. :)

[image]

Comment: I'm getting closer now. I've got the hash feeding to the template, but then the page renders this bundle of joy:

Comment: BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Solspace/Calendar 2.x//EN VERSION:2.0 CALSCALE:GREGORIAN BEGIN:VEVENT UID:90673aa44905cb97755248aa0ab82f15@solspace.com DTSTAMP:20170610T201009 DESCRIPTION:Short Event Description DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170514 DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170515 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20170610T235959Z;INTERVAL=1 SUMMARY:Main Calendar Event END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT UID:902e9db3ee99d81531785b3dd6866865@solspace.com DTSTAMP:20170610T201009 DESCRIPTION:Citizens Bond Oversight Committee Meeting - Measure H (CBOC) DTSTART:20171127T180000 DTEND:20171127T200000 SUMMARY: CBOC Measure H 11-27-2017 END....

Comment: Here's our dev URL so you can see what we're attempting: https://netraising.info/district-calendar/

Comment: The URL is NOT to be accessed by the browser. Instead, the URL is to be copy and pasted by the user into the user's calendar app (Subscription URL).